# Craft Commerce - Stock And Cart

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce, plugin-craftcommerce3

What if two people have the same item in the cart and it is the last in the stock one of those people finishes the purchase, then technically that product is no longer in the inventory that happens there?